Make changes on a ppd in Ubuntu snap cups
In Ubuntu, how do I modify a ppd file? Ich chose a driver which doesn't 100% match my printer model and tried to do some modifications on it.
The file is located at /var/snap/cups/common/etc/cups/ppd/myoki.ppd.
But without restarting anything, the changes don't have an effect. When trying to open a print dialog from an application, the changes are not visible.
After a while, I found the following commands useful for restarting cups:
sudo systemctl stop cups
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
sudo killall cupsd cups-proxyd
sudo systemctl start cups
sudo systemctl start cups-browsed

But after restarting, my ppd file is reverted to what was there before my modification!
What do I have to do so that my changes are recognized my cups?

the file is in /var. that's the location of modifyable files. those in the squash files are all in  /snap/. the proof: i CAN edit the file, copy it to a backup, make checksums, diff it, edit it again. but after restart cups, the old file is back

Meanwhile, I tried the command lpadmin -p myoki -i '/temppath/myoki.ppd'. It changed the file permanently. Unfortunately, it also broke my working situation, even after restoring the previous file, my printer only prints garbage now

Finally, I discovered that there are more folders involved:

/etc/cups/ - contains static configuration
/var/cache/cups/ - is also used
/var/snap/cups/1058/var/cache/ - also used
/var/snap/cups/common/etc/cups/ppd/ - seems to contain copies from /etc/cups/, with some minimal changes. This filesystem is not readonly, but it doesn't make sense to change it because it will be overwritten.

Finally, I was able to change my queue (or create a new one) by using one of the following commands:
# provided drivers
lpadmin -p oki-mb441 -m foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Oki-B4400-pxlmono.ppd -v socket://1.2.3.4 -E

# my own ppd file
lpadmin -p oki-mb441 -i '/path-to-my/OKI-MB441-pxlmono.ppd' -v socket://192.168.1.7:9100 -E

As a starting point for modifying, I used the files in /etc/cups/ppd/, because the modified files in /var/snap/cups/common/etc/cups/ppd/ only printed garbage.
Another way is extracting a file from the provided drivers:
$ lpinfo -m | grep -i oki | grep 44
foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Oki-B4400-hpijs-pcl5e.ppd Oki B4400 Foomatic/hpijs-pcl5e
foomatic-db-compressed-ppds:0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Oki-B4400-pxlmono.ppd Oki B4400 Foomatic/pxlmono (recommended)    <---

$ /usr/lib/cups/driver/foomatic-db-compressed-ppds cat 0/ppd/foomatic-ppd/Oki-B4400-pxlmono.ppd >/path-to-my/Oki-B4400-pxlmono.ppd

Btw the full sequence for stopping and starting cups (i needed it for restoring a backup) was:
sudo systemctl stop cups
sudo systemctl stop cups-browsed
sudo snap stop cups

sudo snap start cups
sudo systemctl start cups
sudo systemctl start cups-browsed


executing   sudo chattr +i /var/snap/cups/common/etc/cups/ppd/myoki.ppd
will make the file immutable so it cannot be automically changed back to default.
If you need to make more changes do sudo chattr - i /var/snap/cups/common/etc/cups/ppd/myoki.ppd to make it editable again and after editing repeat the first command.
Enjoy!
dont forget to restart the services or reboot after making it immutable...

Nope. I could protect the file from being overwritten, but cups kept working with the old contents. and after 15 minutes i changes back the attribute, restarted - and the old file was back
